# supply trucks not going all the way to the delivery area

Tags: prison-architect

I'm having supply trucks stopping randomly holding up everything and when I dismiss it it goes away perfectly then all the other trucks go to the right spot but then every 5 trucks or so another one will stop and not move.

Answer (score 1):

### Potentially Other Actions Are Occurring

There's not enough info in your question to discern the specific issue. I will say that deliveries do get buggy rather easily, so it could just be that the game's being finicky on you.

Another possibility is that the delivery truck is collecting either Exports or Garbage. With regards to either of these, I do not believe that the truck driver will exit for these pickups and thus you need to have an available workman to load these items.

Be aware, if the truck is stopped waiting for loading of either Exports or Garbage, some worker, somewhere is assigned to the task. If that worker is halfway across the prison and exhausted, it's going to take them ages to arrive.

Therefore, the issue may be a matter of simply ensuring that you've a sufficient number of workers to complete the loading. Also, try to ensure the areas zoned for Exports and Garbage are relatively close to where the truck is stopping to cut down on travel time.